# Exception thrown: read access violation. _Scary was nullptr

Tags: c++, static, singleton

Trying to learn to code using Jim Horton's Beginning C++ Programming with Jim Horton. It's crashing with the following:

```
ZombieArena.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,sf::Texture,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,sf::Texture>>,0>>::_Find_lower_bound<std::string>(const std::string & _Keyval) Line 1704    C++
ZombieArena.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,sf::Texture,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,sf::Texture>>,0>>::_Find<std::string>(const std::string & _Keyval) Line 1457    C++
ZombieArena.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,sf::Texture,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,sf::Texture>>,0>>::find(const std::string & _Keyval) Line 1466  C++
ZombieArena.exe!TextureHolder::GetTexture(const std::string & filename) Line 21 C++
ZombieArena.exe!Zombie::spawn(float startX, float startY, int type, int seed) Line 28   C++
```

The code for this is:

```
    #pragma once

#ifndef TEXTURE_HOLDER_H
#define TEXTURE_HOLDER_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <map>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

class TextureHolder
{
private:
    // A map container from the STL,
    // that holds related pairs of String and Texture
    map< string, Texture> m_Textures;
    // A pointer of the same type as the class itself
    // the one and only instance
    static TextureHolder* m_s_Instance;
public:
    TextureHolder();
    static Texture& GetTexture(string const& filename);
};
#endif
```

The cpp file is:

```
    #include "TextureHolder.h"

// Include the "assert feature"
#include <assert.h>

TextureHolder* TextureHolder::m_s_Instance = nullptr;
TextureHolder::TextureHolder()
{
    assert(m_s_Instance == nullptr);
    m_s_Instance = this;
}

Texture& TextureHolder::GetTexture(string const& filename)
{
    // Get a reference to m_Textures using m_s_Instance
    auto& m = m_s_Instance->m_Textures;
    // auto is the equivalent of map<string, Texture>
    // Create an iterator to hold a key-value-pair (kvp)
    // and search for the required kvp
    // using the passed in file name
    auto keyValuePair = m.find(filename);
    // auto is equivalent of map<string, Texture>::iterator
    // Did we find a match?
    if (keyValuePair != m.end())
    {
        // Yes
        // Return the texture,
        // the second part of the kvp, the texture
        return keyValuePair->second;
    }
    else
    {
        // File name not found
        // Create a new key value pair using the filename
        auto& texture = m[filename];
        // Load the texture from file in the usual way
        texture.loadFromFile(filename);
        // Return the texture to the calling code
        return texture;
    }
}
```

It crashes on the 2nd auto line for the map find. Any ideas???? I'm confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a weird singleton implementation and it's probably the source of issue. Do you have a living and valid `TextureHolder` object when you call `GetTexture` function?

Comment: Odd indeed. Since you're providing a default ctor, I cannot see why your single-instance gateway would have to be a pointer in the first place unless there is some odd polymorphic backend we know nothing about (and even then, I still question this model). Normally you would (a) declare the ctor protected or private, (b) declare a single static `static TextureHolder instance;` within `TextureHolder::GetTexture`, and finally (c) reference that instance via `instance.members` within the body of said-same `TextureHolder::GetTexture`. Or something very similar to that.

Comment: Also, "*it's crashing*" isn't sufficient information. What's the error code, what are the value(s) that caused the crash? The MSVC debugger shows a *lot* more details than just "it crashed".

Comment: uselly Jim Horton also provade sorce code - try compare with what hes doing

Comment: Just downloaded the code from the packt site and ran it, same problem the "crash" was with "Exception thrown: read access violation. _Scary was nullptr". I am not an expert, so I'm asking here for help.

Comment: Did we get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add in the main:

```
// Here is the instance of TextureHolder
TextureHolder holder;
```